# How to change the font of a main bar?

Tags: android, fonts, navigation-drawer

I'm learning to make the sliding menu ( drawer )

I've tried using various solutions of other friends in the group , but none of them worked.

I can not change the font of my main bar. I would put the agency_fb.ttf source (already put the file in the assets folder) Any friend can help me solve this?

My coding was based on this tutorial: Click [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/%22AndroidHive%22)!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzueP.png

Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

i used this before

```
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(this.getTitle());
this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);


//here is xml code
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<com.your.package.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add your font to your project's assets folder - I normally put these in an assets/fonts subfolder. After this, you just have to set up your `ActionBar` with a custom `View`, where you've set the `Typeface` on your `TextView`.  For example:

```
private void setUpActionBar(){
    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

    bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    TextView mTitle = new TextView(this);
    mTitle.setText("SomeTitle");
    mTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
    mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/YOURFONT.ttf"));

    ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    bar.setCustomView(mTitle, lp);
}
```